# When connecting the sense hat using jumping wires, do I need to connect to a ground pin?

Tags: hardware, power, connection, sense-hat, connectors

I want to connect the [sense hat](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/sense-hat/) to a raspberry using [jumping wires](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5c/A_few_Jumper_Wires.jpg/1200px-A_few_Jumper_Wires.jpg). I understand that I need to connect the highlighted pins in [this](https://pinout.xyz/pinout/sense_hat) schema of the pin out.

- But do I also need to connect wires to a ground pin?

  - If so, to which and how many?
  - If not, why not?

One of the reasons that I am unsure about this, is because the ground wires are a sort of highlighted in the linked pin out schema, but not completely like the other required pins..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you connect a Pi GPIO to an external device you also need to connect a Pi ground to that device (you can connect more than one to that device if you want but it is not usually needed).

The blurb includes `Needs 5v and 3v3 power`.

That means you also need to connect the 5V and 3V3 power pins.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Bus connections require a common ground because they require a common voltage, and since inevitably the circuit on both sides are electrically powered, any connection between them requires a common ground.

In this case the hat is being powered by the pi and a 3.3V and 5V pin are indicated, as are the grounds, which may imply that they are all also connected on the hat -- but you only require one since it is very very unlikely there are independent circuits on the board.